# Unable to load PostGIS vector layer into QGIS using python cookbook recipe

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I'm having trouble loading a PostGIS layer using Dufour (from osgeo4w), using the guide at http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html. I just get the 'invalid layer' message. My parameters appear to be perfect.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from ui_townplanning import Ui_TownPlanning
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class TownPlanningDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, iface):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_TownPlanning()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.addPostGISLayer('myhost', '5432', 'glis', 'user', 'pass',
                             'tpadmin', 'planning_application_boundary_validation',
                             'wkb_geometry')

    def addPostGISLayer(self, host, port, dbname, username, password,
                        schema, table, geom_col):
        '''Adds a PostGIS table to the map'''
        uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
        uri.setConnection(str(host), str(port), str(dbname), str(username), str(password))
        uri.setDataSource(str(schema), str(table), str(geom_col), '', str(key_col))
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), str('test'), 'postgres')
        # QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
        if not vlayer.isValid():
            msgbox('Layer not loaded', uri.host(),
                   uri.database(), uri.port(), uri.username(), uri.password(),
                   uri.schema(), uri.table(), uri.geometryColumn())

def msgbox(*args):
    a = [str(i) for i in args]
    text = '\n'.join(a)
    qmsg = QtGui.QMessageBox()
    qmsg.setText(str(text))
    qmsg.exec_()
```

**Code now works after correction**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally had the following line of code to set the datasource:

```
uri.setDataSource(str(schema), str(table), str(geom_col))
```

Since I was **trying to add a view** rather than a table, I had to **specify the key column**, so changing that line to the following worked:

```
uri.setDataSource(str(schema), str(table), str(geom_col), '', str(key_col))
```

Note that the empty string (4th parameter) is where a query can optionally be added.